# PHP - Shell Exec - Powershell and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script which I use php to execute using shell_exec and I execute this file when there is an Ajax call. (I'm using a codeigniter 2 environment)

I call it by Ajax because it takes about 45 seconds to execute the ps file and so I thought i would do it via Ajax so i can give the user a message saying it is loading.

My Ajax function looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"#inline_content", inline:true, width:"650px", height:"235px", overlayClose: false, showClose: false});
        $('#cboxClose').remove();

        var csrf = $('[name="csrf_test_name"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/index.php/ajax/addAccount",
            data: { 
                    csrf_test_name: csrf
                  },
            cache:false,
            success: 
              function(data){
                  if(data == "True"){
                        window.location = "/index.php/private";  
                  }else{
                      $(window).colorbox.close();
                      alert("There was a problem creating your account.");
                  }
              },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                    $('#Loading').hide();
                  }

        }); 


    });
</script>
```

The CI Ajax Controller just grabs the data to feed to the model.

The shell exec function looks like this:

```
function createCompany($companyID, $companyName, $domain){

    $psCompanyName = "t_".$companyID. "_".str_replace(" ", "", $companyName);

    $psScriptPath = "c:\\inetpub\\powershellscripts\\createCompany.ps1";
    $ps = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -companyName '".$psCompanyName."' -domain '".$domain."'");
    return $ps;

}
```

The PS1 file executes fine. $ps should contain the value "True" or "False" (The ps1 has write-output "True" or write-output "False" at the end and I have checked and all of the tasks have been sucessfully executed.

When I replace return $ps with return "True" or return "False" the sucess: section works fine (I'm also not getting anything from error: either), and also when i run the function outside of Ajax, I get a result.

Would this be because Ajax is timing out?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. It was executing the script but I needed to change the shell exec code to this:

```
    $ps = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath -companyName '".$psCompanyName."' -domain '".$domain."' < Nul");
```

Not sure what the < Nul bit does, but it was executing the powershell but caused error 500